# bash not adding current date to file name

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script which backups my source code on a 10 minute basis thru crontab. Script was working until the end of August. It's not working since September 1st. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
date=`date +%e-%m-%y`
cd /home/neky/python
tar -zcf lex.tar.gz lex/
echo $date

mv lex.tar.gz lex-$date.tar.gz
mv lex-$date.tar.gz /home/neky/Dropbox/lex/lex-$date.tar.gz
```

If I execute it manually, it print the current date `4-09-12`, and this error `mv: target ‘4-09-12.tar.gz’ is not a directory`

What could be the problem?

Comment: $date has a leading space and if you do `show lex-$date.tar.gz` you'll see `lex- 4-09-12.tar.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` contains a space when the day of month is a single digit (which also explains why it only stopped working in the new month). That results in your command being split up, i.e.

```
# this is what it you end up with
mv lex.tar.gz lex- 4-09-12.tar.gz
```

Use `date +%d-%m-%y` instead which will give you `04-09-12` (note `%d` instead of `%e`).

---

If you really want a space in the name, you'll need to quote your variables, i.e.:

```
mv lex.tar.gz "lex-$date.tar.gz"
mv "lex-$date.tar.gz" /home/neky/Dropbox/lex/
```

Answer (score 0):

The character `%` (part of your date format) is a special one in cron scripts, so you need to escape it.

Comment: OK, I see the script is not in your your crontab, you just call it from crontab. In this case you obviously don't need to quote `%`